# Dictionary with list as values to multilevel index Dataframe with list objects as values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary in this format:

```
dict = { (A1,col1):3, (A1,col2):[1,2,3] ... (B1,col1):2,(B1,col2):[2,3]}
```

Is it possible to construct a dataframe with a multilevel index of

```
      A1                    ... B1
      col1     col2           col1     col2
0      3      [1,2,3]           2      [2,3]
```

I tried to construct the dataframe with `pd.DataFrame(v)` but I get a `Value Error all arrays must be the same length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.DataFrame(dd.values(), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(dd.keys()))).T
```

Output:

```
    A1              B1        
  col1       col2 col1    col2
0    3  [1, 2, 3]    2  [2, 3]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have worked, I get ```TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()```.

Comment: I think something to do with the dd.values() part, since there is an integer in col1.

Comment: I've worked around it using ```items()``` rather than values, but I get an extraneous level. Thanks for the help!